# Error in Oracle insert stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, insert

Insert stored procedure statement in Oracle using SQL Developer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE T_Department_INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    insert INTO T_Department(dept_id, dept_name, dept_location, manager_id)
    values(select case count(*) when 0 then 1 else max(dept_id) + 1 (end.from T_Department),
           par_dept_id, par_dept_name, par_dept_location, par_manager_id);
      NULL;
END T_Department_INSERT;
```

Comment: 1) Do not mix `INSERT INTO VALUES/SELECT` syntax, 2) Avoid `MAX(...) + 1`, it does not scale well, consider using SEQUENCE

Comment: thanks for your reply 
can you post the code after editing!?
thanks in advance

Comment: Please post an example of data, explaining what your procedure should do

Comment: well, iam using sql developer, i created new table called 'T_Department' has 'dept_id,dept_name,dept_location,manager_id' 
i want to make a stored procedure to insert new row using this code 
" CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE T_Department_INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    insert INTO T_Department(dept_id,dept_name,dept_location,manager_id)
    values(select case count(*)when 0 then 1 else max(dept_id)+1(end.from T_Department )
    ,par_dept_id,par_dept_name,par_dept_location,par_manager_id);
      NULL;
END T_Department_INSERT;" 

and show error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you use (SQL Developer) makes no difference on the correct answer. Here is one possibility:

```
    CREATE TABLE t_department
    (
       dept_id         INTEGER
     , dept_name       VARCHAR2 (20)
     , dept_location   VARCHAR2 (100)
     , manager_id      INTEGER
    );

    CREATE SEQUENCE t_department_seq;

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_department_trg
       BEFORE INSERT
       ON t_department
       REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
       FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       :new.dept_id   := t_department_seq.NEXTVAL;
    END t_department_trg;

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE t_department_insert (
       p_dept_name       IN t_department.name%TYPE
     , p_dept_location   IN t_department.location%TYPE
     , p_manager_id      IN t_department.manager_id%TYPE
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO t_department (
                 dept_name, dept_location, manager_id
                   )
            VALUES (p_dept_name, p_dept_location, p_manager_id);
    END t_department_insert;
```